# How to enable cancel button in the installation page

Tags: inno-setup

cancel button in the installation wizard is disabled when the SQLCMD is executing scripts .
is there any way to enable the cancel button so that we can terminate installation while executing scripts

Comment: Your question makes not much sense, but I guess you're going to enable button which is disabled for a good reason. But well, you can do it if you set `WizardForm.CancelButton.Enabled := True`.

Comment: WizardForm.CancelButton.Enabled := True only enables the button but click does not happen.

Comment: As I thought, the click event action is internally ignored for some reason. When do you execute your scripts ? At which installation stage do you need to cancel your script execution ?

Comment: after all the files are copied to target folder in the installation page,it invokes the SQLCMD to run the scripts for database, at that point of time install page waits for sqlcmd to complete the task and cancel button is disabled. So i need to enable the cancel button  and click to cancel the script execution.

Comment: To be more precise. Are you executing your scripts from the `[Run]` section of your script ? Or from somewhere else ? We need to know the precise time when (or how, if it's not from a script section) are you executing them. Could you elaborate this a bit more in your question, please ?

Answer (score 1):

The button is not disabled, but the click is being ignored as the Inno isn't responding or is being blocked by the "long running" SQLCMD process.

It's not possible in Inno to make this responsive as it is out of it's control. While you may be able to run the commands asynchronously, there is no easy way to pass on the cancel notification without potential data loss.